# Auto-self modifying function in virtual runtime environment in Rebol

Tags: rebol

I want to auto-modify a function once it has executed itself (context is remote execution in a virtual runtime environment that shares a code-block which simulate stack of functions (because this stack is shared I want to reset everything each time for next command call) see http://askblogautomation.com/developers-guide/) like this for example ( for full context see http://askblogautomation.com/install-wordpress/):

```
install-wordpress
set 'install-wordpress func[][do read http://askblogautomation.com/install-wordpress/]
```

I want to genericize the above lines with

```
execute 'install-wordpress
```

Where execute is as below

```
execute: func[lit-word-command [lit-word!]][
  do get lit-word-command
  block-command: []
  append block-command [do read]
  append block-command to-url rejoin [http://askblogautomation.com/ lit-word-command]
  set lit-word-command func[] block-command
]
```

But when I tried it, it gives error:

> ** Script Error: execute expected lit-word-command argument of type:
>   lit-word

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either change the invoking line:

```
 execute to-lit-word 'install-wordpress
```

Or change the function spec:

```
execute: func[lit-word-command [word!]][
```

But not both!

Comment: Thanks, I'm too confused between word! and lit-word! :)